# php Graphical statistics take the Data from a database?

Tags: php

i have a site like rapidshare allows users to upload files and register
i want to add a Graphical statistics showing the daily upload *files*, registered *users* and files *views*....etc
I want to take the Data from a database
is there any good library that easy to use....
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the  [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) its  support complex graphing plotting and data will come from MYSQL database and also supports the 2D/3D graphs